# ошибка при вызове метода с сервера на клиентской части C# WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

Есть служба WCF в ней есть метод, который обращается к таблице в базе данных и в случае нахождения записи возвращает целочисленное значение. НА клиентской части вызываю метод при нажатии на кнопку и возникает исключение, что сервер не смог обработать запрос. Так как я новичок не понимаю ни как узнать что за ошибка на сервере, ни как исправить ее.
Код серверной части:

```
public int Authorise(string login)
        {
            var usera = AppData.db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == login);
            if (usera != null && usera.Unit != "Приемная")
            {
               
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (usera != null)
                {
                    return usera.ID;
                }
                else return -1;
            }   
        }
```

Код клиентской части:

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                int a;
                a = client.Authorise(log.Text);
                if (a > 0)
                {
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new nach(a));
                }
                else if (a == 0)
                {
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new cho());
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Неправильно введен логин!");
        }
```

Файл конфигурации хоста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBeh">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
        <services>
   <service name="ServiceDM.ServiceDocMan" behaviorConfiguration="mexBeh">
    <endpoint address="ServiceDM.ServiceDocMan" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ServiceDM.IServiceDocMan" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8301" />
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8302" />
     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   </service>
  </services>
    </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```